# Show submit button only when select fields are not empty

Tags: jquery, forms, button, submit

I am having trouble only showing the submit button in the form with the select field that is selected. I have drop-downs and since the forms and buttons all have the same class names it shows and hides all of them instead of just the submit button in that form.

I have tried .closest and .siblings as well as .this and nothing is working. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="wp_cart_button_wrapper">
<form method="post" class="wp-cart-button-form" action="" style="display:inline" onsubmit="return ReadForm(this, true);">
<input type="hidden" id="_wpnonce" name="_wpnonce" value="4ef19837f1" style="display: none;">
<input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/products/" style="display: none;">
<div class="wp_cart_variation_section">
<span class="wp_cart_variation_name">Logo Color  : </span>
<select name="variation1" class="wp_cart_variation1_select" onchange="ReadForm (this.form, false);"><option value=" "> </option><option value=" Black "> Black </option><option value=" Green "> Green </option><option value=" Red "> Red </option><option value=" Blue"> Blue</option></select><br></div>
<input type="submit" class="wspsc_add_cart_submit" name="wspsc_add_cart_submit" value="Add to Cart" style="display: none;"> 
<input type="hidden" name="wspsc_product" value="Suzuki Digital Fuel Gauge ( )" style="display: none;">
<input type="hidden" name="price" value="69.99" style="display: none;">
<input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="0.001" style="display: none;">
<input type="hidden" name="addcart" value="1" style="display: none;"> 
<input type="hidden" name="cartLink" value="https://motorgremlin.com:443/products/" style="display: none;"><input type="hidden" name="product_tmp" value="Suzuki Digital Fuel Gauge" style="display: none;">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="" style="display: none;">
<input type="hidden" name="hash_one" value="9a905bd16028ff467e67534f28f2a986" style="display: none;">
<input type="hidden" name="hash_two" value="6c9ed95be3289ffa48e727369b49e5c2" style="display: none;">
</form>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(".wp_cart_variation_section select").on('change', function() {
        var x = this.selectedIndex;
        if (x == "") {
           $(".productButton, .wp_cart_button_wrapper input").hide();
        } else {
           $(".productButton, .wp_cart_button_wrapper input").show();
        }
    });
$(".productButton, .wp_cart_button_wrapper 
input").css("display","none");
```

I am wanting to only show the button in that form only. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What's your HTML like?

Comment: I just added it. Its from a plugin and I am just trying to hide the button until the user selects the options in the select input.

Answer (score 1):

> ...it shows and hides all of them instead of just the submit button in that form.

Use [`:submit` selector](https://api.jquery.com/submit-selector/) to target the submit button.

```js
$(".wp_cart_variation_section select").change(function () {
  var state = this.selectedIndex > 0;

  $(".productButton:submit, .wspsc_add_cart_submit").toggle(state);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wp_cart_button_wrapper">
  <form method="post" class="wp-cart-button-form" action="" style="display:inline" onsubmit="return ReadForm(this, true);">
    <input type="hidden" id="_wpnonce" name="_wpnonce" value="4ef19837f1" style="display: none;">
    <input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/products/" style="display: none;">
    
    <div class="wp_cart_variation_section">
      <span class="wp_cart_variation_name">Logo Color  : </span>
      <select name="variation1" class="wp_cart_variation1_select" onchange="ReadForm (this.form, false);">
        <option value=" "> </option>
        <option value=" Black "> Black </option>
        <option value=" Green "> Green </option>
        <option value=" Red "> Red </option>
        <option value=" Blue"> Blue</option>
      </select>
      <br>
    </div>
    
    <input type="submit" class="wspsc_add_cart_submit" name="wspsc_add_cart_submit" value="Add to Cart" style="display: none;">
    <input type="hidden" name="wspsc_product" value="Suzuki Digital Fuel Gauge ( )" style="display: none;">
    <input type="hidden" name="price" value="69.99" style="display: none;">
    <input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="0.001" style="display: none;">
    <input type="hidden" name="addcart" value="1" style="display: none;">
    <input type="hidden" name="cartLink" value="https://motorgremlin.com:443/products/" style="display: none;">
    <input type="hidden" name="product_tmp" value="Suzuki Digital Fuel Gauge" style="display: none;">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="" style="display: none;">
    <input type="hidden" name="hash_one" value="9a905bd16028ff467e67534f28f2a986" style="display: none;">
    <input type="hidden" name="hash_two" value="6c9ed95be3289ffa48e727369b49e5c2" style="display: none;">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Edited above. We were referencing the wrong `class`, this edit should nail it.

Comment: This works for showing and hiding the submit button, but it is still showing all the submit buttons. I have multiple forms with the same classes and how would I make it to where it only shows the button in that form not all the forms?

Comment: @DerekBuckingham Why don't you update your code and add another form showing how it's not working? It's hard to determine where the selector needs to apply when you can't see the related elements.

Comment: If all of the button/fields container have the same class `wspsc_add_cart_submit`, then the submit button should be just right inside of the form, right? Would be helpful if you can add some more details in the HTML structure.

Comment: Its from a WP plugin, and thats pretty much the whole form itself HTML wise. If you want to see what I am referring to you can go to https://motorgremlin.com/products to see what I am trying to do. For some reason the forms dont have an option for required fields and I am just trying to make sure people fill out the areas that I will need before they purchase.

Comment: I believe I figured it out and added this to your code. 
    $(".wp_cart_variation_section select").change(function () {
 var state = this.selectedIndex > 0;
  
 $(this).parent().next(".productButton:submit, .wspsc_add_cart_submit").toggle(state);
});

Answer (score 0):

Your selector doesn't appear to match the submit button. Try this instead.

```js
var x = this.selectedIndex;
$(this).closest(".wp-cart-button-form").find(".wspsc_add_cart_submit").toggle(x && x > 0);
```

Comment: This works to show and hide the button, but it still is showing the submit buttons for all the forms and not just the form they fill the field out in. I have multiple forms with the same classes and it just shows all the buttons once I check the selected box.